# Why do I converge only using a parameter wrapper in PyTorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, bayesian-networks

I'm writing an implementation of Bayesian Dropout, and the following code worked after several hours of debugging:

```
class DropoutLayer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, dropout_rate):
        super(DropoutLayer,self).__init__()
        self.M = Parameter(torch.normal(torch.zeros(n_in,n_out),0.01))
        self.m = Parameter(torch.rand(n_out))

        # 1-p is used to be consistent with original dropout definition
        self.z = Bernoulli(torch.tensor([1-dropout_rate]))

        self.W = Parameter(torch.mm(
        torch.diagflat(self.z.sample(sample_shape=(n_in,))),
        self.M))



    def forward(self,x,act):
        activation = torch.mm(x,self.W) + self.m

        out = act(activation) 
        return out
```

However, I do not seem to understand, why the matrix multiplication in self.W needs a parameter wrapping. I would assume once I nominate self.M to be a parameter in autograd, I would not need to do it for any values which use it further down the line. Why do I need it here?

After adding this wrapper, the neural net converges without a problem.
Could you tell me why is it the case and if there is a simpler substitute for this solution which I don't like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you **don't need** to pass `self.M` into `Parameter`, as the gradient **does not** go through it. You `forward` function only uses `self.W` and `self.m` (plus activation, although you really should pass it to the constructor, not `forward`...).

All `self.M` is some kind of random normal tensor created at the same time as module and it's simply initializing your `self.W` matrix to concrete values. So `self.W` is a separate tensor, it's not computationally dependent on `self.M` in any way.

Comment: Indeed, this clears it up for me. So the general guideline for using Parameter is to add the tensors which are used in forward, right?

Comment: Yeah, the ones which change according to gradient in the backward pass.